# How do I Call a method from other Class

Tags: objective-c, call

I'm having some trouble figuring out to **call methods** that I have in **other classes**

```
#import "myNewClass.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize txtUsername;
@synthesize txtPassword;
@synthesize lblUserMessage;

- (IBAction)calculateSecret {

NSString *usec = [self calculateSecretForUser:txtUsername.text 
                       withPassword:txtPassword.text]; 

    [lblUserMessage setText:usec];
    [usec release];
} 
...
```

myNewClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myNewClass : NSObject {
}
- (NSString*)CalculateSecretForUser:(NSString *)user withPassword:(NSString *)pwd;

@end
```

myNewClass.m

```
#import "myNewClass.h"

@implementation myNewClass

- (NSString*)CalculateSecretForUser:(NSString *)user withPassword:(NSString *)pwd
{
    NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ -> %@", user, pwd]; 
    return a;
}

@end
```

the method CalculateSecretForUser always says

> 'MainViewController' may not respond to '-calculateSecretForUser:withPassword:'

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword "self" means the instance of your current class. So you are sending the message `calculateSecretForUser:withPassword` to `MainViewController` which does not implements it. You should instantiate `myNewClass` and call it :

```
- (IBAction)calculateSecret {
    myNewClass *calculator = [[myNewClass alloc] init];

    NSString *usec = [calculator calculateSecretForUser:txtUsername.text 
                        withPassword:txtPassword.text]; 

    [lblUserMessage setText:usec];
    [usec release];
    [calculator release];
}
```