# Where should I call a function for calculations in an Objective-c iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, encryption, aes

Please excuse my inexperience with Objective-C. I've only been playing with it for a couple weeks.

I am trying to test out Apple's methods for encrypting and decrypting data (in this case an NSString). The end goal is to have the user type something in a text area, and then encrypt it.

I am using a basic single-view application in Xcode and added in these two files (From [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/60926-aes-encryption-objective-c-php.html) ):

NSDataEncryption.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (AES256) 
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
@end
```

and NSDataEncryption.m

```
#import "NSDataEncryption.h"

#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData (AES256)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577366/how-do-i-call-a-method-from-other-class), I am calling the method like this:

```
#include "NSDataEncryption.h"

//...

NSString * key = @"ThisIsAKey";
    NSDataEncryption *encryptionClass = [[NSDataEncryption alloc] init]; //Errors: "Use of undeclared identfier 'encryptionClass'" and "Use of undeclared identifer 'NSDataEncryption'"
    NSData * newData = [encryptionClass AES256EncryptionWithKey:key]; //Errors: "Use of undeclared identfier 'encryptionClass'" and "Use of undeclared identifer 'NSDataEncryption'"
```

I've tried putting this inside main() and inside a new function in another class (ViewController):

```
- (IBAction)someFunctionName { code here }
```

**The Big Question:** Why isn't Xcode accepting NSDataEncryption as a class, nor letting me call its function, AES256EnryptionWithKey? Should I be performing the encryption somewhere else in the App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDataEncryption is not a class. It's a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) on the standard NSData class. This means it 'extends' the NSData class with two methods: `- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;` and `- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;`. These both return NSData and take one NSString as parameter.

You call them like this:

```
NSData *dataToBeEncrypted = [NSData data]; //Put your data here
NSString *key = @"ThisISAKEy";
NSData *newData = [dataToBeEncrypted AES256EncryptionWithKey:key];
```

You can use these methods for encrypting/decrypting a string:

```
- (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];

}

- (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey:key]
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "data"? The thing being encrypted is the string, correct? Also I'm getting the error "No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'AES256EncryptionWithKey'" on the last line.

Comment: These methods return an NSData object created from another NSData object. If you want to encrypt a string you need to convert it to NSData first. There are examples of this on the forum you linked to. I added them to my post. But really, you should have looked there first. Also make sure you included the correct header files.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I was misunderstanding some fundamental Objective-C stuff there and didn't realize it. (Putting [dataToBeEncrypted AES...] is like the dot operator in Java, right? dataToBeEncrypted.Method();)    It seems like I may still missing a header file because I'm still getting that error message ""No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'AES256EncryptionWithKey"".  Is NSDataEncryption.h the only thing I need to include? (This file is actually pasted in my project.)

Comment: Ah I see. The correct method signature is `AES256EncryptWithKey:`, instead `AES256EncryptionWithKey:` which you have now. And yes, it is 'like' the dot operator in Java. Except Objective-C is completely different in the concept of sending messages to objects. But that's really basic Objective-C stuff. I suggest you read up on Obj-C basics :).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encrypted = [data AES256EncryptionWithKey:@"RandomString"];
```